# How to update npm package from a local folder

Tags: node.js, github, npm

I cloned some npm package from github and put the package in a local folder, e.g.

```
c:\git\package
```

I used "npm install -g" to install the package, which works really well.

```
npm install -g c:\git\package
```

However, when I did some change in the code of the package, e.g. checked out some branch. I couldn't use "npm update" to update the installed package. I have tried:

```
npm update -g
```

and

```
npm update -g packagename
```

or

```
npm update -g folderpath
```

Neither worked. I have to use "npm install" to reinstall it again for updating, which is wasting time to reinstall all dependencies.

Why does npm only support install from folder but not update from folder? If it does support, what shall I do? Thanks.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this is what `npm link` is for.

Comment: I stumbled upon this error and figured out that if I do NPM install from a local folder and make changes to that local folder it will directly reflect on to your code. No need to do an NPM update.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of `npm install` from a local directory, try [`npm link`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link), which creates a globally-installed symlink to the directory.

As stated [in the docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link), this is a two-step process:

1. In package directory:

   ```
   $ npm link
   ```

   This creates a symlink to the current folder in npm's global installation directory.
2. Somewhere else, where you want to use the module:

   ```
   $ npm link <pkgname>
   ```

   This will create a symlink in your project's `node_modules/` folder to the global installation.

Comment: Nice, it worked like a charm! One more question, if I just need to use the package globally, I only need to run "npm link" in the package directory, right?

Comment: And how do we automate this? When a new coworker checks out the repository he runs directly into an exception because the link is not yet created.. right? Unacceptable solution for us then ^^ Well i try it a s a pre-install script...